# Rally Lookback API filter on a custom field

Tags: api, rally, lookbackapi

We are using a Kanban board and have a custom field on UserStories called KanbanState.  Can I filter the lookback query on this field? (property: 'KanbanState' value: 'Accepted').  Or can I only filter on the ScheduleState field?  It appears I have to use ScheduleState, but wanted to verify.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely query/filter on custom fields using Lookback API. You just have to prefix the field name with a "c_". The following query sample illustrates a query for all User Story snapshots with a KanbanState of "Accepted" from 19-Sep-2012 to present.

```
{ "_TypeHierarchy" : "HierarchicalRequirement",
  "_ValidFrom" : { "$gte" : "2012-09-19T00:00:00.000Z" },
  "c_KanbanState" : "Accepted"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, just found the c_ prefix as well.